# React Native slow / freeze whet i call ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic() [Ethers js 5.5.1]

Tags: react-native, blockchain, javascriptcore, ethers.js

when I call `ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic('....')` my application freeze for 5/10 seconds and go next (is slow but work). If run application on emulator, work fine, but on android or ios I have this problem.
I tried to follow the docs on https://docs.ethers.io/v5/cookbook/react-native/ but i have the same problem

```
import "react-native-get-random-values"
import "@ethersproject/shims"
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const account = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/49? There is a workaround bit it ain't pretty.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ethereumjs-wallet`, `bip39` and `ethers` together to create a wallet.

```js
import * as Bip39 from 'bip39';
import { Wallet } from 'ethers';
import { hdkey } from 'ethereumjs-wallet';

/**
 * @dev Create Wallet from Mnemonic
 * @param mnemonic = Mnemonic phrase
 * @param index  = Account index
 * @returns wallet
 */
const createWallet = async (mnemonic: string, index: number): Promise<Wallet> => {
  const seed = await Bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
  const hdNode = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
  const node = hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'`)
  // m/44'/60'/0'/0
  const change = node.deriveChild(0);
  // m/44'/60'/0'/0/{N}
  const childNode = change.deriveChild(index);
  const childWallet = childNode.getWallet();
  const wallet = new Wallet(childWallet.getPrivateKey().toString('hex'));
  return wallet
}
```

I have test this in both IOS and Android and was able to create a HD Wallet instantly.

To use `bip39` in `React Native`  environment you have to apply some patches to `bip39`.
You can refer how [MetaMask mobile-app](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile) has applied those patches [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/blob/main/patches/bip39%2B2.6.0.patch) using [`patch-package`](https://www.callstack.com/blog/say-goodbye-to-old-fashioned-forks-thanks-to-the-patch-package).
In my patch I have imported `randomBytes` from `react-native-crypto` instead of `randombytes` module

```js
var {randomBytes} = require('react-native-crypto')
```

Versions of node modules I have used,

```
bip39 = 2.6.0
ethers = 5.5.3
ethereumjs-wallet = 1.0.2
react-native-crypto = 2.2.0
```